# yvals.h C4514 warning on Windows SDK 7.1 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I am compiling with `cl.exe` version `_MSC_FULL_VER == 160030319` with warning level at 4.  I get this warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\yvals.h(773) : warning C4514: 'std::_Mutex::_Mutex' : unreferenced inline function has been removed
```

Which is this bit of source code:

```
__thiscall _Mutex(_Uninitialized)
{   // do nothing
}
```

`yvals.h` is included in `stdint.h` which I am including like so:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4514)

#include <stdint.h>

#pragma warning(default:4514)
```

But it *still* does not get rid of the warning.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hmm...it seems that `yvals.h` is getting included somewhere else other that `stdint.h`. If I remove the `default:4514` the warning goes away

Comment: I wrapped all my includes but it still persists

Comment: I don't get this - I just looked at the C preprocessor output (`/P`) and everything seems in order - the `yvals.h` offending line is correctly wrapped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/506985/disabling-warnings-explicitly-on-locale-std-locale-still-causes-them-to-surface). Someone reported it as a bug, but it was closed as by design. The answer is that the warning doesn't kick in until the end of the translation unit. Quote:

> Thanks for reporting this issue. I've resolved it as By Design because
>   the 4514 and 4710 warnings are emitted at the end of the translation
>   unit (a translation unit is a source file and all of its included
>   headers). That's why disabling them for part of the translation unit
>   has no effect. Although the line numbers might make it appear as if
>   the compiler is emitting these warnings in the middle of the
>   translation unit as it's compiling the code, that's not the case.
>
> Warning 4514 "unreferenced inline function has been removed" is
>   emitted at the end of the translation unit by the compiler front-end
>   (responsible for parsing C++) because only then can it determine that
>   nothing in the translation unit references that inline function. It
>   looks up the function's line number, but whether the warning is
>   emitted or not depends on whether it is enabled at the end of the
>   translation unit, not whether it was enabled while compiling that
>   function.

So you either need to keep it always disabled or not worry about it.

Comment: that's frustrating.  I'll just disable it across the whole build - we _have_ to be warning free for continuous integration :(  Thanks for the answer :)!!